# SQL Выборка последних строк пока сумма столбца будет меньше определенного количества

Tags: sql, sql-server, запрос

Пример таблицы 'table':

```
|table1----|--table2--|--table3---|  
|----------|----------|-----------|  
|User------| 5000-----|-15-02-2016|  
|admin-----| 3500-----|-18-03-2016|  
|guest-----| 2000-----|-19-03-2016|  
|guest2----| 200------|-23-03-2016|  
|guest3----| 2000-----|-24-03-2016|
```

Нужно выбрать дату первой строки из последних строк где сумма строк по столбцу table2 больше 4000. То есть, по таблице выше в конце должно выйти 19-03-2016

Comment: Диалект SQL какой ? На MySQL надо решать переменными, на других СУБД оконными функциями.

Comment: И "последних строк" - это значит сортировать задом наперед и складывать, берем самую последнюю запись, если меньше прибавляем предпоследнюю и т.п. ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Mike, Да. Именно это и надо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select *
  from (
        select col1, col2, dt,
               sum(col2) over(order by DT desc) as S
          from Table
       ) A
 where S<500
```

В данном примере выбираются записи с кумулятивной суммой колонки `col2` меньше 500 с сортировкой по колонке `DT` в обратном порядке. Т.е. берутся последние по дате записи.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! То что нужно. Немножко подкорректировал под себя и все вышло